# Сериализация объектов с меньшим количеством свойств

Tags: c#, json

Есть список объектов абстрактного класса.
Сам этот класс менять не могу, так как он пренадлежит пакету из Nuget.
Этот класс имеет 10 свойств.

Хочу этот список сериализовать например с помощью `JsonSerializer` в строку, но сохраняя объекты с 3 свойствами из 10.

Знаю что могу перебрать этот список создав список с каким то мини классом и потом сериализовать.

А есть какой то вариант изящнее ?

Для примера (GPT создал):

```
public abstract class CarBase
{
    public abstract bool IsAvailable { get; }

    public virtual bool IsElectric => false;

    public bool IsLuxury => !IsAvailable;

    public virtual string Manufacturer { get; }

    public virtual int Year { get; }

    public virtual string Model { get; }

    public virtual string Color { get; }

    public virtual double EngineSize { get; }

    public virtual int NumberOfDoors { get; }

    public virtual string VIN { get; }

    public abstract string LicensePlate { get; }
}
```

И сериализовать к примеру только 3 свойства Year / Model / Color

Накинуть игнорирование именно в этом классе на некоторые свойства не могу - так как сторонняя библиотека.

Comment: в зависимости от способа сериализации будут разные способы настройки какие поля и в каком виде должны будут сериализовываться

Comment: @Grundy Если я правильно понял, я сериализовал так JsonSerializer.Serialize(List<MyClass>). Но нет необходимости во всех 10 свойствах. А накинуть игнорирование именно в этом классе на некоторые свойства не могу - так как сторонняя библиотека.

Comment: _А накинуть игнорирование на некоторые свойства не могу - так как сторонняя библиотека_ - сторонняя библиотека где? Добавь в вопрос информацию о том, что используешь JsonSerializer. Отредактировать вопрос можно с помощью кнопки [edit] под вопросом

Comment: @Grundy в проекте пакет из Nuget

Comment: И пример класса добавь, что бы был примерный набор полей какие есть и какие хочешь выбрать. А также укажи, что сам класс изменять не можешь

Comment: @Grundy обновил.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно через анонимный тип. Например, есть класс

```
public class Data
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }
    public string Prop3 { get; set; }
}
```

Например, надо взять только первые 2 свойства.

```
List<Data> list = ...;
string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(list.Select(item => new
{
    Prop1 = item.Prop1,
    Prop2 = item.Prop2
}));
```

Также при таком исполнении можно переименовать свойства при присваивании.

---

Либо создать свой тип данных и переносить значения в него. Можно даже создать статический метод для конвертации данных.

```
public class MyData
{
    public string Prop1 { get; set; }
    public string Prop2 { get; set; }

    public static MyData FromData(Data source)
    {
        return new MyData
        {
            Prop1 = source.Prop1,
            Prop2 = source.Prop2
        };
    }
}
```

```
string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(list.Select(item => MyData.FromData(item)));
```

Comment: Aepot - как всегда спасибо!
Но как я понял, грубо говоря без конвертации похожей на тот же перебор не обойтись. Будь то анонимный или подготовленный класс. Думал вдруг можно что то типа такого)

string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize<List<SmallClass>>(List<BigClass>)

Comment: @Xzizz нет, так не получится. Если бы исходный класс с данными был бы в вашем коде, всё было бы проще. Начиная от пометкой аттрибутом свойств `[JsonIgnore]`, заканчивая добавлением интерфейса и апкастом (типа как в вашем коде).

Comment: А в настройках Serialize нельзя указать список свойств или правила выбора? через `JsonTypeInfo` или что-то подобное?

Comment: @Grundy для этого есть `[JsonIgnore]`, он и является реализацией выбора.

Comment: Не, это настройка через определение класса, я имел ввиду опции передаваемые в сам метод сериализации

Comment: @Grundy таких нет.

Comment: jsonTypeInfo есть

Comment: @aepot всё понял, спасибо!

Comment: @Grundy возможно где-то в недрах опций резолверу типа свойства можно сказать что свойство надо скипнуть (атрибуты с подобным поведением же есть), но это получится более монструозное и менее поддерживаемое решение. Я бы сказал, что такое стоит использовать только в промышленных масштабах, когда есть например 3п-либа, и там сто тысяч типов, которые надо кастомить при сериализации в рантайме. С таким же успехом можно и свой тип в рантайме заэммитить, но смысл в этом какой?

Answer (score -3):

Для сериализации/десериализации вы можете использовать библиотеку `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`, а именно аттрибуты `JsonPropery` для указания имени данного свойства в Json объекте, либо аттрибут `JsonIgnore` для игнорирования этого свойства во время сериализации

Comment: Автор сказал, что он не может модифицировать код класса с данными.